# alignment in Ghidra and IDA

Tags: ida, ghidra

I see in my IDA it does automatically "**align 10**" after the end of a fucntion.
I wanted to know how to make the same in Ghidra manually like IDA does.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Press <kbd>t</kbd> and it should be in the expanded view for the generic lib.